# Postgres - How to reference a primary key to a non unique value

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I've been working on this assignment I got lately and it has me stumped for how I have to reference a specific table. So let's say I have a table of works from the museum and it contains two primary keys, combined makes it alphanumeric.

```
CREATE TABLE Works (
wrk_charid pdkeyone,
wrk_numid pdkeytwo,
wrk_name workname,
wrk_type worktype,
wrk_subtype worktype,
wrk_donate donator,
wrk_creation workDate,
wrk_acquistion workdate,
wrk_insurance insurance,
wrk_desc description,
wrk_curloc locationname DEFAULT 'Storage'
REFERENCES LocationAreas 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
PRIMARY KEY (wrk_charid, wrk_numid),
UNIQUE (wrk_charid, wrk_numid)

);
```

So that is my table for works, and we have a separate table for materials. However, many works have more than one value for their materials, causing an error that it is not unique. So far I have the table for my materials as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Materials (
mt_charid pdkeyone,
mt_numid pdkeytwo,
mt_material materialdesc,
PRIMARY KEY (mt_charid, mt_numid)

);
```

I don't know exactly how I can reference my works to my materials without running into a uniqueness error. Could someone please help push me in the right direction for what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: The `UNIQUE (wrk_charid, wrk_numid)` may be omitted; it is implied by the `PRIMARY KEY` clause.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advice! I was given a kind of wishy washy answer in class and thought it would be best to keep it in, but thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the relationship is many to many (one work can have many materials, one material can be present in many works)
You should create a new Table to add the relationships between them. (Basically which work has which material).
Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Works_Materials (
    wrk_charid work_pdkeyone,
    wrk_numid work_pdkeytwo,
    mt_charid material_pdkeyone,
    mt_numid material_pdkeytwo,
    PRIMARY KEY (work_pdkeyone, work_pdkeytwo, material_pdkeyone, material_pdkeytwo)
    FOREIGN KEY (work_pdkeyone, work_pdkeytwo) REFERENCES Work(pdkeyone, pdkeytwo)
    FOREIGN KEY (material_pdkeyone, material_pdkeytwo) REFERENCES Material(pdkeyone, pdkeytwo)
);
```

Comment: Okay... And to add in materials I would add it in this table instead of just adding them into the materials table? Would you mind providing an example as to how I would enter this data then? I'm kind of lost as to how adding to the table will work then, even if it's from a file...

Comment: No you still add the materials to the materials table this is just a link table thay links materials to works.

Comment: Thanks for the example! However, I seem to have a problem with my Materials_pkey. Since it's also charid and numid it violates the primary key constraint of uniqueness. That being said, should I change my unique key in my Materials to be my description instead... Actually I don't think that will work because those are not unique as well.

Comment: You can always add an id to the material to make it unique, but you should think first if there is something that identifies them. For example, can two different works share a material? If not, then why not? If they can, then what is a material from their point of view?

Comment: Alright! Thank you for the help! I think I figured it out by adding an alternate id value for materials so that remains unique and I can insert within the table! Thank you!